# How do I make a letter/number be replaced with any letter/number on any key press

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script where I type any word into a text box, for example: "Homework", but whenever I try to type, the letter I want is replaced, so homework would be: "J3s95nz8" instead of "Homework". Here is how I think I would do it.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var string = getElementById('myTextBox').value;
    var characters = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    var letter = pickRandom(characters);
    replace(string with letter); //something like this?
}
onkeypress() {
    myFunction();
}
```

How would I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `keypress` event listener to the document where you perform the replacement:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress',()=>{
       var string = getElementById('myTextBox').value;
       var characters = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
       var letter = pickRandom(characters);
       string.replace("new char","old char")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random element from `characters` and replace it with the last entered character as follows:

```js
let inp = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
function myFunction(){
    var string = inp.value;
    var characters = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    let rand = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
    inp.value = string.substring(0,string.length-1)+rand;
}
inp.addEventListener("input",function(){
     myFunction();
});
```

```html
<input id="myTextBox"/>
```